# how to write function in CLASSNAME for styling JavaScript React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui, classname

i'm trying to iterate over an array that have Position of cell numbers that i need to color. I need to pass that to my ClassName material-UI styling. How can i possibly do that?

**current code**

`className={ column.orderPosition === workingColumn ? classes.buttonSelected :  classes.buttonNormal}`

however, i need to see if column order position is more than 1 column and keep the style with it. 
this is my array name:
**AnonymizationAssignmentArray**.

**columnOrderId** ( this is the variable that have the position number ) so all those cells needs to be styled in a different way in className.

if i can write a function that would return the values, or how can i iterate over the array to allow only those cell positions to be colored in a specific way.

Comment: Could you send us your code using https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: dont know how to share it via codesandbox. 

my problem is to color the column headers according to the function that is to be performed on it. like if it is column 0 and we choose to do ADdition in that column then it has to be red, If we choose column 5 and we choose to do multiply then it has be to be green. again if we choose 2 and we choose to do addition in that then it has to be red.  how to style this?